# Django Rest - Create method, returns error 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-405

I created a view to create a new object. In the DRF default page everything works fine, but when I try to create an simple HTML page as a user interface (by adding renderer_classes and template_name to the view), the following error occurs: 405  Method Not Allowed.

I created an html page to retrieve/update a client detail information, and it works fine. However, I was unable to do so to create a new client.

models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
    client_rut = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True, verbose_name="RUT")
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name="Nombre Cliente")
    client_region = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Region")
    client_tel = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, verbose_name="Telefono")
    client_email = models.EmailField(blank=True, verbose_name="E-mail")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Activo")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['client_rut']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client_rut + ' - ' + self.client_name
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # /clients/
    url(r'^$', views.ClientView.as_view(), name='clients'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ClientDetailView.as_view(), name='clientdetail'),
    url(r'^create/$', views.ClientCreateView.as_view(), name='clientcreate')
]
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns, allowed=['json', 'html', 'xml'])
```

serializers.py

```
class ClientListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='clients:clientdetail',)
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = '__all__'

class ClientDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
#this view works fine
class ClientDetailView(views.APIView):
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientDetailSerializer
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'clientdetail.html'

    def get(self, request, pk):
        client = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=pk)
        serializer = ClientDetailSerializer(client)
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'client': client})

    def post(self, request, pk):
        client = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=pk)
        serializer = ClientListSerializer(client, data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'client': client})
        serializer.save()
        return redirect('clients:clients')

# this one does not
class ClientCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientListSerializer
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'clientcreate.html'

    def post(self, request):
        Client.objects.create()
        return redirect('clients:clients')
```

clientcreate.html

```
{% load rest_framework %}

<html><body>
    <form action="{% url 'clients:clientcreate' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-xs-6 ">
            {% render_form serializer %}
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Grabar">
        </div>
    </form>
</body></html>
```

clientdetail.html is almost identical to clientcreate.html, save for this:

```
<form action="{% url 'clients:clientdetail' pk=client.pk %}" method="POST">
```

I think I've seen all 405 related questions and I just couldn't solve my problem (doesn't necessarily mean the answer's not out there though).

Hope someone can help me with this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Why on earth are you using Django REST Framework to render an HTML page? You'd be much better off using Django's generic views for that.

Comment: Just for learning purposes. I used django's generic views already, but now i'd like to know how json objects communicate with the most basic front end possible. Any insights on my question though?

Comment: Fair enough. A 405 should mean that you're using a method you haven't implemented, so I'd check the method in the network tab of your browser's dev tools. It might also be useful to create a test to reproduce the error using the Django test client. Then you can set a breakpoint in the view using pdb or ipdb and explore what's going on from inside the view.